# Probability that ace is the last card dealt out of 13 randomly chosen cards

Tags: combinatorics

My problem is this:

**A deck of ordinary cards is shuffled and 13 cards are dealt. What is the
probability that the last card dealt is an ace?**

Here is my work so far:

probability that there is at least one ace in the 13: 1-(C(52,13)-C(48,13))/C(52,13) = .3038

probability that there is an ace left at the end of dealing 12 cards: 12!/13! = .076923

probability of both of those happening: .3038*.076923 = .02337 = 2.34%

does this look correct? Thank you so much in advance.
Nolan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making it too complicated.  Just shuffle the deck and look at the $13^{\text{th}}$ card.  It will be an ace with probability $\frac 4{52}$.  Just like the first card.  One error is that the chance that an ace is last among 13 cards given that there is at least one ace is greater than $\frac 1{13}$ because you might have more than one ace.

Comment: Wow yeah, Cant believe I didn't realize that. Half of this seems to be making sure you're thinking of the problem in it's simplest terms. Thank you so much